# I need to sync text and speech using python

Tags: python, text, text-to-speech

I want to write a Python program that will print some text and will read it at the same pace. How should I go about this?
heres my code so far:

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')   # getting details of current speaking rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)     # setting up new voice rate
engine.say('i need your help stack overflow!!')      # type the thing you want to say
engine.runAndWait()
'''
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Have you encountered a specific error that you'd like help with? If so, please provide the error message. It will help our community here better understand where you are encountering issues.

Comment: thanks for replying the program the way you see it now will just read the text you type in engine.say('') . what I want is to make some text print at a certain pace that will mach the talking speed.

Comment: @matt were you able to figure this out?